# How to save clients (guest) account details in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am creating an appointment diary for instructors and their clients.

`Users` table have necessary fields like following

```
username | email | password | type (admin, client) | first_name | last_name | current_team_id
```

Instructors will have `type` field set to `admin` and default for other users is `client`. Instructors can be a part of multiple team or instructing schools that's why `current_team_id` points to `teams` table id.

Now my issue is with the `clients` account.

1. I want Instructor to be able to add a client on the fly at the time of booking. So it means they will not have any appointments yet with the Instructor.
2. Display clients who have booked an appointment with that `team` in the past or clients added by Instructor.

So an Instructor should only see his clients at the time of booking.
I thought of adding an extra column in `users` table `guest` and at the time of booking run a query to get all clients from `bookings` table who have booked at least 1 appointment with the instructor. It will not show clients added by Instructor but have not booked any appointment yet.

Required field for Clients is only their `first_name` and `last_name`. I want a solution where in future if client decides to sign up, I can connect all the past appointments.

Thank you

Comment: What is your **interface** like? Are your clients and instructors interfacing with the SQL directly? Or are you using some sort of server-side language like PHP to handle the inserts, and providing them with an HTML form? Because your issue `1` is a gaping security vulnerability if you allow them to edit SQL directly...

Comment: @ObsidianAge I am using `PHP` for CRUD operations. I just want to know table structure for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a `bookings` table that references the client *and* admin from the `users` table as foreign keys. To achieve this, you will want an additional `id` column on the `users` table:

**Users**:

```
id | username | email | password | type (admin, client) | first_name | last_name | current_team_id
```

**Bookings**:

```
id | time | client_id | instructor_id
```

**Teams**:

```
id | any_other_data
```

Point `1` becomes the default in this scenario; clients don't have any bookings with the instructor *until* there is a corresponding row in the `bookings` table. That is what you check for, with:

```
SELECT * FROM users u
INNER JOIN bookings b
WHERE u.id = b.client_id
```

As for point `2`, you can work out whether or not there has been a previous booking for a client with a particular instructor (or team) by joining the teams table and checking whether the IDs match:

```
SELECT * FROM users u
INNER JOIN bookings b
INNER JOIN teams t
WHERE u.id = b.client_id
AND u.current_team_id = t.id
```

Comment: In scenario `1`, I only want to show Instructors the clients they have added. In other words, clients added by Instructor B should not be in the list of Instructor C when there is no row in bookings table.

Comment: Also `current_team_id` is relevant only for `instructors` and not for clients.  `current_team_id` indicates the team, Instructor is part of.